# Using Command line to select a file, reading the file and storing contents as a matrix (PYTHON, Visual Studio)

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a file with N rows and M columns. I would like to use the command line (python) to specify the file and then store its contents into a matrix in this form [0,0,0],[0,0,0]...

I have this so far, but when I run in through terminal, it does not ask for the text file.

```
import sys

def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f]
    return data

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: {0} <Data Points>".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(1)

    file1 = sys.argv[1]

    data_points = read_data(file1)
    print(data_points)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the file path as an argument when calling your program.

`python script.py /myfile`

Or whatever arguments your `script.py` file needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not call the `main()` function. We define the `main()` function, but it will not run until called. I added a call to the `main()` function at the bottom of the script.

```
import sys

def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f]
    return data

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: {0} <Data Points>".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(1)

    file1 = sys.argv[1]

    data_points = read_data(file1)
    print(data_points)

main()
```

When you run the script, you will want to run it on the command line using a command that looks similar to this:

`$ python3 myscript.py mydata.csv`

Where:

- `myscript.py` is the name of your script
- `mydata.csv` is the name of your data file